# Taking a screenshot of a UserControl using MVVM Light

Tags: c#, .net, mvvm-light

I'm having a problem using MVVMLight to take a screenshot and have created the following horrible workaround. Maybe you can help me to do it better without using Code-behind.

The MainWindow of my application has a menu option "Take screenshot". It also has a TabControl with dynamically created Tabs.

```
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:OverviewViewModel}">
                    <local:OverviewView/>
                </DataTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:MzViewModel}">
                    <local:MzView/>
                </DataTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:TabViewModel2}">
                    <local:TabView/>
                </DataTemplate>
```

The "TakeScreenshot" command sends a message to the TabViewModel using MVVMLight:

```
public ICommand SaveImage { get { return new RelayCommand(SaveImageExecute); } }

private void SaveImageExecute()
{
    MessengerInstance.Send(Index, "Picture");
}
```

In the TabViewModel I receive the message and call a function:

```
MessengerInstance.Register<int>(this, "Picture", TakePicture);


void TakePicture(int tabnumber)
{
    if (tabnumber == _tabNumber)
    {
        _screenshot = true;
        ScreenshotParam++;
    }
}
```

The ScreenshotParam is bound to the Width property of a button in the View and Triggers the SizeChanged-Event. This triggers an ICommand in the ViewModel and provides the ViewModel with the UserControl needed to take the screenshot using a CommandParameter.

```
<Button Width="{Binding ScreenshotParam}" Visibility="Hidden" Height="0">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="SizeChanged">
            <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding Screenshot}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=UserControl}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</Button>
```

Finally I can get my screenshot in the ViewModel:

```
public ICommand Screenshot { get { return new RelayCommand<object>(OnScreenshot); } }

        private void OnScreenshot(object obj)
        {

            UserControl uc = (UserControl)obj;
            RenderTargetBitmap renderTargetBitmap =
            new RenderTargetBitmap((int)uc.ActualWidth, (int)uc.ActualHeight, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
            renderTargetBitmap.Render(uc);
            PngBitmapEncoder pngImage = new PngBitmapEncoder();
            pngImage.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(renderTargetBitmap));
....
}
```